# Concatenate strings and variables in assignment of new variable in smarty

Tags: templates, smarty, concatenation

I want to concatenate an already assigned variable and save it to a new variable, something like this:

```
{assign var=permCat value="de.admin"}
{assign var=objectName value="myClass"}
{assign var=objectNameUpper value=$objectName|ucfirst}
{assign var=editPerm value=$permCat|cat:"canEdit"|cat:$objectNameUpper}
```

So, the resulting `$editPerm` should be: `de.admin.canEditMyClass`

How can I do this? Currently, it throws an error: `Cannot use string as array offset...`

Comment: On which of the four lines the error is thrown?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The error you describe cannot be caused by the given code. I assume you are trying to build a string "de.admin.canEditMyClass" to use as a variable `{$builtString.foo}`. That's where the error occurs, because smarty does not magically convert your string to a variable reference.

If you're using Smarty2:

```
{assign var=objectName value="myClass"}
{assign var=objectNameUpper value=$objectName|ucfirst}
{assign var=editPerm value="canEdit"|cat:$objectNameUpper}
{$de.admin.$editPerm.foo}
```

If you're using Smarty3:

```
{$de.admin.{"canEdit"|cat:{"myClass"|ucfirst}}.foo}
```